# Merge multiple rows based on single column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarization

I am having following table:

```
A  B  C   D    E

1  NA we  are  here
1  hi we  NA   here
1  NA NA  are  there
2  u  NA  are  where
```

I want my output table to be:

```
A  B   C   D   E
1  hi  we  are here
2  u   NA  are where
```

I have tried the following :

```
my_fun <- function(x) x[!is.na(x)]

buildingCopy %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(my_fun))
```

it gives error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `E` must be length 1
>   (a summary value), not 3

Can anyone help me to achieve required data frame.

Comment: How would you like it to group the values, so for example on group 1, you have 2 values not na in column C. and 3 in E. R doesn't know how you want to aggregate these (and nor does Stack),  can you explain how the values should be selected

Comment: i column C, i am having similar values i.e. 'we' so i want we, in column C I have 2 values namely 'here' and 'there', I would like to take first value which I get  i.e. 'here'

Comment: You can get the first non na value like so:

    my_fun <- function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function in the following way:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  if_else(any(!is.na(x)), na.exclude(x)[1], NA_character_)
}
```

First it checks whether there are any non-missing values and returns the first non-missing value and `NA` otherwise.

If you only use the funciton once you could also do:

```
buildingCopy %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(if_else(any(!is.na(.)), na.exclude(.)[1], NA_character_)))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#       A B     C     D     E    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 hi    we    are   here 
# 2     2 u     NA    are   where
```

Or you can use the condition in a `summarise_if`-statement:

```
buildingCopy %>% 
  add_row(A = 2, B = "u", C = NA_character_, D = "are", E = "where") %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise_if(funs(any(!is.na(.))), funs(na.exclude(.)[1]))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#       A B     C     D     E    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 hi    we    are   here 
# 2     2 u     NA    are   where
```

**Data**

```
buildingCopy <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                               B = c(NA, "hi", NA, "u"), 
                               C = c("we", "we", NA, NA), 
                               D = c("are", NA, "are", "are"), 
                               E = c("here", "here", "there", "where")), 
                          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The base R function `na.omit()` can be used here

```
library(dplyr)
my_fun <- function(x) na.omit(x) %>% first()
buildingCopy %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(my_fun))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>       A B     C     D     E    
>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1     1 hi    we    are   here 
> 2     2 u     NA    are   where
> ```

#### Data

```
buildingCopy <- readr::read_table(
"A  B  C   D    E
1  NA we  are  here
1  hi we  NA   here
1  NA NA  are  there
2  u  NA  are  where")
```